# Latex: conflict titlesec and tikz packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, errors, titlesec

I am using the `IEEEtran` class and I also call in my preamble the `titlesec` and `tikz` packages. 
If `tikz` is not called my code runs fine. Otherwise, (when calling the `tikz` package) I am given this error log:

```
/usr/local/te/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code
.tex:22: No room for a new \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.22 \newdimen\tikzleveldistance

? w \dimen .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.20 \newdimen\tikz@lastysaved

?
```

I would thank if somebody may give me feedback on this conflict.

Comment: Are you using TikZ pictures in your titles or something that gets repeated? I'm curious why you use `titlesec` package with IEEEtran. Can you include a MWE?

Comment: No, I am not. I want to insert a flowchart in a figure environment.

Comment: Thanks, \usepackage{etex} did what I was looking for. I am using the conference mode of the IEEEtran class; however, I needed to adjust the formatting due to special requirements of a conference .